# pass div to props react without children

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a `<div></div>` (some html/jsx content) into a FC but not from the children props (it's already used for something else).

I wanna have something like that:

```
<Component props={{ 
  title: "hello",
  description: 
    {
      <>Hello <h1>world</h1> </>
    }
/>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: you can not render it then. you need to use `dangerouslySetHTML` to render it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** :

You can use `Fragment` if your version is above 16.2 :

like this :

```
<Child
    text={
          <Fragment>
            This is an <strong>HTML</strong> string.
          </Fragment>
        }
      />
```

**Older version :**

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render a HTML content from a prop.

pass the html as a normal string prop

`<Component text="This is <strong>not</strong> working." />`

And render in in the JSX code like this:

```
<div className="header-title-right wow fadeInRight" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.text}} />
```

Just be careful if you are rendering data entered by the user. You can be victim of a XSS attack

Here's the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Example : [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gvvfyw?file=src/App.js)

Comment: i was expecting another way, less risky, thanks !

Comment: @sshmaxime Updated the answer. You can use `Fragment` . Check the stackblitz link

Comment: check the question, i modified something, we are almost there, thanks for your help so far !

Comment: ok bro, doing it